# pip install torchviz==0.0.2

Tags: pytorch, torch

I am getting this mistake
"ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from torchviz) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch"
when trying to run the command pip install torchviz==0.0.2. I am using python version 3.9.12 and torch version 1.12.0.
Does anyone know why I can’t install torchviz via the command window or what the problem is?

Comment: This is likely an issue with the python version not actually being 3.9.12, which can occur in virtual environments. Make absolutely sure that you're using 3.9.12 by running 'python --version'.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the version and turns out I use python version 3.8.10

Comment: How about we close this issue with an accepted answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

This is likely an issue with the python version not actually being 3.9.12, which can occur in virtual environments. Make absolutely sure that you're using 3.9.12 by running 'python --version'.